# Recursion solution doesn't seem correct

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, summation

I'm studying real analysis at the moment on my own.  So I don't have a professor to ask if I'm not sure about my answer to an exercise from my text.  So I'll ask you guys.

The question is

> Let $d$ and $a_1$ be numbers.  Define $a_j$ for each integer $j\gt 1$ by the equation $a_{j+1}=a_j+d$, and suppose that $a_j \ne 0$ for all $j\in \Bbb N$.  Find the sum $$\sum_{j=1}^n \frac 1{a_ja_{j+1}}$$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

After doing a partial fraction decomposition, using the telescoping property, and then using $a_n = a_{1+(n-1)} = a_1+d(n-1)$ (which I think is right), I get the answer as $$\frac 12\left[\frac 1{a_1} + \frac1{a_1+1} + \cdots + \frac 1{a_1+d-1} - \frac{1}{a_1+d(n-1)+1}-\frac 1{a_1+d(n-1)+2}-\cdots - \frac 1{a_1+dn}\right]$$  which seems way too overly complicated to be the answer.Does this seem like the right solution?  If not, am I on the right track?

Comment: Partial fractions, telescoping are right. We get $\frac{1/d}{a_i}-\frac{1/d}{a_i+d}$.  Now there should be nice telescoping.

Comment: Oh.  I see what I did -- I didn't recognize $a_j+d=a_{j+1}$ and so did the telescoping part the hard way (also I wrote down a $2$ instead of a $d$ at one point).  So the answer is $\frac 1d\left[\frac 1{a_1}-\frac{1}{a_1+nd}\right]$ isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right about $a_n = (n-1)d + a_1$. Now,

$$\frac1{a_j a_{j+1}} = \frac1{a_j(d + a_j)} = \frac1{d} \left( \frac1{a_j} - \frac1{d + a_j} \right) = \frac1{d} \left( \frac1{a_1 +(n-1)d} - \frac1{a_1 + nd} \right) $$

I hope that you can see how it telescopes now.